# MIPS: Label com número(?) no Branch on Not Equal

Tags: ciência-da-computação, arquitetura-computadores, mips

Ok, tenho o seguinte exercício:

> Levando em consideração os valores presentes nos registradores $t0 = 0x0000001A, $t1 =
>   0x00000006 e o seguinte código a ser executado pelo processador MIPS, responda:

```
add $t2, $t0, $t1
srl $t3, $t2, 1
addi $t3, $t3, -8
div $t2, $t3
mfhi $t3
mflo $t4
sll $t3, $t3, 9
sub $v0, $t2, $t3
bne $t3, $t4, -32
jr $ra
```

> (a) O desvio condicional é realizado?

Pode parecer uma pergunta besta, porém eu não entendi esse "-32" na penúltima linha do código. Esse -32 está indicando o endereço na memória? O que é? Ou está errado de propósito para a resposta da questão a) ser falsa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!

Quando fiz a disciplina de Organização de Computadores (Arquitetura de Computadores), utilizei o MARS[1] como simulador e lá diz que o terceiro argumento da instrução *Branch on not equal* (BNE) deve ser um *label*, ou seja, um loca nomeado para onde seu código deve saltar.

Porém, procurando no MIPS Instruction Reference[2], a sintaxe da instrução bne é apresentada da seguinte forma: `bne $s, $t, offset`. Por offset, eu entendo que é um deslocamento de endereço mesmo, o que no final das contas é o que ocorre "por baixo dos panos" quando usamos um label.

Executei seu código no MARS apenas mudando o -32 por um label e a condição do `bne` é atendida e acontece o salto. Portanto, eu responderia que, sim, realiza o desvio.

1. http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/
2. http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html